# Bootstrap 2.3.2 popover not working with Angular

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, popover

I´m trying to use a bootstrap popover in my Angular website. I don´t know why it´s not working. I have read many posts saying you have to initialize the popover. I try to do it, but still not working.

I think I know how it works, indeed I have created this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/po3LfEgkRot6TVKJykWp?p=preview which is working, however when I try to do the same in my site, it´s not working.

I paste my website code:

In HTML:

```
           <i id"deposit"             
               style="color: #08c; cursor: pointer" 
               rel="popover"                       
               data-original-title="Title"> Test                            
            </i>
            <!-- your popup hidden content -->
            <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none;">
                <p>This is the content</p>                  
            </div>
```

In my angular controller:

```
$('#deposit').popover({ 
            html : true,
            trigger: 'hover',
            container: 'body', 
            content: function() {
              return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equal sign. Change `id"deposit"` to `id="deposit"`.

#### Full Example

```
<i id="deposit"             
   style="color: #08c; cursor: pointer" 
   rel="popover"                       
   data-original-title="Title"> Test                            
</i>
```

Comment: Yes Babak, you are right, sorry it was a typo, but still not working.

Comment: Do you see any messages in your console?